# Microsoft Access VB.NET Url

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I want to make my vb.net program read my access database. Because I edit the file often, I want to open the access database via url. ***How can I do that?***

Comment: You forgot to mention what kind of application you're building. A better description of what you mean by *open the access database via url* wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Jimi I'm building a store app with my programs. In the access file I have the program's name,description,current version and more. I uploaded the project to dropbox and made the link direct. How can I import the database to my app via url? Sorry if my english is bad ;(

Comment: *What kind of application* refers to its *architecture*. Is it a Desktop app (in this case, what Platform), or a Web app (ASP.Net and such)? Other? -- You can store an Access database in a network drive, multi-user is harder with a Desktop app: in this case, choose a database Server. A Web app, definitely not. -- You need to visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other information about asking questions.

Comment: @Jimi Windows Forms Net framework

Comment: It is a very bad idea to try to use an Access database in that way. If you want an online database then do it properly. Use SQL Server or MySQL or some other proper RDBMS and then expose it via a web service. Your app can then make calls to that web service.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  i don't want to pay for sql

Comment: No one pays for "sql". SQL is a language, not a database. If you're talking about SQL Server, the Express edition is free and can handle databases up to 10 GB. If you're talking about MySQL then it's free too.